# How to set minimum width of a view to match parent

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm creating some custom views and drawing everything required in canvas.
I can calculate the minimum width required to draw my view. But I need to follow the following rules,

- if view's required width is less than parent's width, set view width to parent width.
- if view's required width is more than parent's width, set parent's width to view's width.

Parent is inside ScrollView.

Parent is extended from LinearLayout with a vertical orientation.

Source code available on request.

Answer (score 1):

> if view's required width is less than parent's width, set view width to parent width.
>
> if view's required width is more than parent's width, set parent's width to view's width.

Keep child width as always match_parent and all you have to do is adjust the parent layout width. It will do the magic for you :)